Why is this not a net antennae? (Altium Designer)
Why would this not be flagged as a net antennae in Altium Designer (25)?
This is a GND pour covering all of the bottom layer in my PCB design, and the TH vias (mostly meant to conduct between layers 1 and 2) are connected to it, with the pour stretching all the way up and creating this very long, thin neck. I do not want to use blind vias due to cost.
How can I prevent this within design rule check (so that I don't have to draw a manual cutout)?


The easy way is to move the traces closer together so it doesn't pour there.

You can increase the polygon clearance rule to put an end to that nonsense and improve manufacturability.

You can place a keep out in the area you don't want the pour.
